# How to use custom chunk sizes to read in pandas data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a massive 5GB+ csv file I am trying to read into a pandas data frame in python. The csv file has over 100 million rows of data. The data is a simple timeseries data set, and so a single timestamp column and then a corresponding value column, where each row represents a single second, proceeding in chronological order. Though when trying to read this in as a pandas data frame, given the enormous size of the csv file, I run out of memory to allocate to reading in this data on my machine. To avoid this problem, I am trying to read in this csv data in chunks, using the following code:

```
Chunksize = 2500000
for chunk in pd.read_csv("my_file.csv", chunksize=Chunksize):
    print(chunk.head())
```

This works, where I am able to read in my csv file into data frame chunks of 2,500,000 rows each (the last chunk would of course be the remainder of < 2,500,000 rows).

However, I want an explicit reason for my chunk size, as opposed to just a "best judgement" selection, such as the 2,500,000 row chunk size I use above. What I want to figure out is, how can I set my chunk size to be custom based on a given parameter? Specifically, I want each of my chunks to be all of the rows corresponding to unique months in my time series data set. And so let's say this time series dataset has for example 3 years, 5 months, and 9 days of data, and so 3x12 = 36 months + 5 months = 41 months and 9 days of data = 42 chunks, where I have 41 chunks of full month-long second-resolution data and then the last chunk made up of 9 days worth of 1-second resolution data.

How can I augment the `chunksize` argument in `pd.read_csv()` to accommodate a custom parameter such as delimiting by months? I am guessing this would involve some sort of manipulation in the timestamp as a datetime object, but I am not sure how to actually specify this delineation, since the `chunksize` argument just requires a single value.

Answer (score 0):

This was part of a homework assignment from "Data Wrangling with Python" authors Sarkar and Roychowdhyry, Packt> publishing 2019, page# 185

substitute your file for "BostonHousing.csv"

This is exercise 64: Combining Skiprows and Nrows to Read Data in Small Chunks

Produces 5 chunks of 10 rows each from your file

```
# List where DataFrames will be stored    
list_of_dataframe = []

# Number of rows to be read in one chunk
rows_in_a_chunk = 10

# Number of chunks to be read (this many separate DataFrames will be produced)
num_chunks = 5

# Dummy DataFrame to get the column names
df_dummy = pd.read_csv("BostonHousing.csv",nrows=2)
colnames = df_dummy.columns

# Loop over the CSV file to read-only specified number of rows at a time
# Note how the iterator variable i is set up inside the range
for i in range(0,num_chunks*rows_in_a_chunk,rows_in_a_chunk):
    df = pd.read_csv("BostonHousing.csv",header=0,skiprows=i,nrows=rows_in_a_chunk,names=colnames)
    list_of_dataframe.append(df)
```

##########################################

To get your chunks run:

list_of_dataframe(0)  # gives you the first chunk of ten rows

list_of_dataframe(4)  # gives you the last chunk of ten rows

- may the force be withyou